# Error text file generates when creating an exe file using exe4j

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, exe4j, synthetica

My program is created using Netbeans and I need to make a .exe to make a setup file using innosetup, so I used exe4j to make the exe. This is what generates in a text file when all the steps are done.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
        org/netbeans/lib/awtextra/AbsoluteLayout
    at app.initComponents(app.java:78)
    at app.<init>(app.java:39)
    at Main$1.run(Main.java:32)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
        org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that `org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout` is available in the `classpath` at runtime. You can locate `AbsoluteLayout.jar` in the NetBeans distribution, as shown below:

```
$ find . -name \*AbsoluteLayout\*
./Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/modules/ext/AbsoluteLayout.jar
./Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/sources/org/netbeans/lib/awtextra/AbsoluteLayout.java
…
```